# Copying file from sharepoint in a web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Currently our application is working with a Word Document which is stored locally in the file system.  It reads it and manipulate it, returning the updated document to the user. I have the following code:

```
var tempFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".docx");
        File.Copy(fileName, tempFileName);
        if (!File.Exists(tempFileName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to create file: " + tempFileName);

        using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(tempFileName, true))
```

it was creating a temp file and copying the word doc and then manipulating the temp file.  This way the original word doc is untouched.

We were recently asked to move the word doc into sharepoint, i'm able to connect using the WebClient class and verify the file exists, but I'm not able to figure out how to copy the file from Sharepoint.  I've tried:

```
            var client = new WebClient { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials };
        // Create a request for the URL.         
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileName);
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        //check response status
        if (String.Compare(response.StatusDescription, "OK", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            client.DownloadFile(fileName, Guid.NewGuid() + ".docx");

            //URL exists so that means file exists  
            return true;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("File \"" + fileName + "\" do not exists");
```

Problem is when I call DownloadFile it works, but I don't know where that file is sent.  Is there a way to connect to the file in sharepoint and just copy it over to the users tempath as the original way?

Comment: Check "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\"

Comment: I didn't see it there, but I was just able to get it to work but supplying it the full name in the DownloadFile 2nd parameter. I passed in the value I had for var tempFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".docx"); and its generating as before in the tempfolder